# Need Only New and Updated Entries from ATOM, RSS

Tags: parsing, rss, feed, atom-feed

Is there an ATOM Client or framework that enables capture of a feed entry EXACTLY once?

If not, what is the best architecture?

We would like to parse an ATOM feed, persisting all syndication feed entries locally as individual records (in database or file system).  These records may have to be deleted periodically for efficiency.  So client must keep track of which entries it has already looked at, independently - of the said persistence.

Comment: Some research of the subject of the question should be performed by the author before posing questions here at SO.

Comment: Still Looking.  Best resource (so far) on this topic - Section 7.3.2 of "RSS and ATOM in Action" By Dave Johnson -Using ROME Fetcher.  Particularly, the DiskFeedInfoCache implementation.

Comment: Probably the latest ROME https://rometools.jira.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Fetcher not working, yet.  Posted on forum. http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=59971&stqc=true

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own, per working solution developed.  In one word, the architectural solution to capturing only new and unique entries from a syndication feed is - CACHING.

Specifically, the entries must be stored by the client to support the logic "does the feed have anything new for me?".  I believe there is no shortcut to this "client-side" solution.

Conditional-GET is not a complete solution, even if supported server side by the syndicated feed.  For instance, if the client client does not send the exact *If-Modified-Since* time-stamp, the server can ignore the header and simply generate all entries again.  Per [Chris Berry, Bryon Jacob. Updated 10/27/08](http://atomserver.codehaus.org/docs/protocol_reference.html),

> ...a better way to do this is to use the start-index parameter, where the client sets this value to the end-Index, returned in the previous page. Using start-index ensures that the client will never see the same response twice, or miss Entries, since several Entries could have the same "update date", but will never have the same "update index".

In short, there is no standard server side solution guaranteeing "new/unique". The very idea of "uniqueness" is a client-side issue anyway and same opinion may not be shared by the server.  From that perspective, it would be impossible for server to satisfy all clients.  And, anyway, the question does not pertain to developing a better syndication server, but a smarter client, therefore, Caching is the way to go.

Cache implementation must persist between feed polls and the time-to-live (ttl), time-to-idle (tti) properties of entries stored in cache must be set appropriately to BOTH limit the performance/size of cache AND also to adequately cover the feed's oldest entries between polling cycles.  Cache could be memory resident, database, file system or network array.  A product like EHCache, ehcache.org, provides just about all the functionality needed.

The feed entries may persisted as-is, but the best (most efficient) method would be to  identify contents, or combinations thereof, that make them unique.  Methods like serialization in java or Google's Protocol Buffers may be used to create unique compact keys to persist in the cache.  In my simple solution, I did not even bother storing the entries, just the keys generated as an MD5 hash of a couple of entry fields by which I defined how an entry would be unique for my purpose.

Hope this [flowchart](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B01JiMtrxBDmZDJMdXZfMG42MGs/edit?usp=sharing) is helpful.

Comment: Your link to the flowchart requires that you grant access to the document on google drive. I'd like to see it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com)? Its a software as a Service platform that does just that: fetches feeds, parsed them and sends the new entries to your endpoints when they're available.

Comment: Thanks, Julien.  But adding a SaaS broker (of sorts) between the ATOM server and client just introduces a third architectural dependency.  As the Superfeedr documentation says "your XMPP client must be connected at all times...you will messages if client is offline".  Since maintaining live connection is not practical, and this per Superfeedr's own examples, we will still be polling - not the ATOM feed, but Superfeedr.  That said, I would like to see an Superfeedr capability integrated into the client or server itself.

Comment: I believe the architecture feature I am looking for is termed "Conditional GET" which is part of HTTP/1.1 spec, although rarely implemented.

Comment: Per RFC 2616 9.3 (w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html): The semantics of the GET method change to a "conditional GET" if the request message includes an If-Modified-Since, If-Unmodified-Since, If-Match, If-None-Match, or If-Range header field. A conditional GET method requests that the entity be transferred only under the circumstances described by the conditional header field(s). The conditional GET method is intended to reduce unnecessary network usage by allowing cached entities to be refreshed without requiring multiple requests or transferring data already held by the client."

Comment: Alejandro Abdelnur and Nick Lothian have provided an example FeedReader utility class as part of some ROME Fetch distributions to detect if an ATOM server supports conditional GETs.

Comment: If you're not aboslutely able to keep a socket open at all times, you can also check our PubSubHubbub API :) (HTTP webhooks based...), and no you won't be polling Superfeedr at all as we would push you the data thru either protocol! Unfortuantely Conditional GET is not there yet but still honestly does not solve the problem either, because you would still have to poll the feed quite often if you want to be timely. Happy to follow up by email :)